# For a month vs. A month, Past Tense?

Tags: past-tense, time

What is the difference between these two sentences?

> My expensive shoes only lasted a month.
>   My expensive shoes only lasted for a month.

1. Could we omit “for“?
2. Does the phrase “a month” always indicate the past tense?

Thanks very much

Comment: to last for some amount of time. to last an amount of time. Easily found.

Answer (score 0):

> Could we omit “for“?

Yes, *for* is optional here.

> Does the phrase “a month” always indicate the past tense?

No. For example I could say

> > I am going to Europe for a month next year.

(Note: I can't explain the specific rule, but *for* is not optional in this example. I suppose it's idiomatic whether *for* is require, optional, or not allowed for each particular verb)